# why setVisibility in fragment doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, fragment, visibility, progress

the ProgressBar doesn't disappear in the fragment also items aren't loaded in the RecyclerView, When the code was in the body of onCreate of the main activity ,it was working

I am making fragment that contains ProgressBar and RecyclerView with retrieving data from firebase database , I added setVisibility at the end of onDataChange method so that after getting all the data and store it in the array list , the ProgressBar disappear

```
RecyclerView offersRecycler;
ArrayList<offer> offers;

OffersAdapter offersAdapter;

View fragment_layout;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fragment_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false);

    // Offers RecyclerView
            offersRecycler = fragment_layout.findViewById(R.id.offersRecycler);
            offers = new ArrayList();
            offers_init();
            offersAdapter = new OffersAdapter(offers,getContext());
            offersRecycler.setAdapter(offersAdapter);
            offersRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false);
}


private void offers_init() {
    DatabaseReference db_offers = db_ref().child("offers");

    db_offers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                ProgressBar loadingOffers = fragment_layout.findViewById(R.id.loadingOffers);
                loadingOffers.setProgress(10);

                for (DataSnapshot offer_item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String id = offer_item.getKey();
                    String title = offer_item.child("title").getValue().toString();
                    String rating = offer_item.child("rating").getValue().toString();
                    String orders_number = offer_item.child("orders_number").getValue().toString();

                    offer offer_object = new offer(id,title, rating, orders_number);
                    offers.add(offer_object);

                    offersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"title",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loadingOffers.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });



}
```

I expect the ProgressBar to hide and the array loaded into the RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

fragment_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false);

// Offers RecyclerView
        offersRecycler = fragment_layout.findViewById(R.id.offersRecycler);
        offers = new ArrayList();
        offers_init();
        offersAdapter = new OffersAdapter(offers,getContext());
        offersRecycler.setAdapter(offersAdapter);
        offersRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


// Inflate the layout for this fragment
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false);
}
```

^ This is your code snippet. What you are doing is - inflating a layout `fragment_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false)` and using `fragment_layout` to get the instance of `RecyclerView`. This is fine.

But at the end of the method, you are inflating a new layout and returning that. So the Android framework uses that `View` instead of `fragment_layout` to set the Fragment view. All the views in `fragment_layout` won't be shown since it's never added to the fragment and hence you don't see any changes in the RecyclerView.

At the end of the `onCreateView` method, you should just return `fragment_layout`.

Answer (score 1):

in your CreateView, change

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false);
```

by

```
return fragment_layout;
```

You call the layout, init recyclerview, but recall the "blank" layout

Also, avoid underscore for method or variable name, it's not the java convention